# Strange Layout using jQuery DataTables v1.9.4

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, datatables

I just download the DataTAble 1.9
I tried to make a basic demo, here the JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>                                  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">;
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">;
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>

<link href="resources/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" / >
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js"</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#table_id').dataTable();
 } );
</script>
</head>

<body
<table id="table_id">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
<td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
<td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But that's the result :-(

https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t1.0-9/1795493_1374615349481499_1647144929_n.jpg

And this the console messages. Thanks.

```
23:06:38.708 Propiedad desconocida 'zoom'. Declaración rechazada. demo_table.css:36
23:06:38.709 Se esperaba una declaración, pero se encontró '*'. Ignorado hasta la siguiente        declaración. demo_table.css:82 
23:06:38.709 Se esperaba una declaración, pero se encontró '*'. Ignorado hasta la siguiente declaración. demo_table.css:157
23:06:38.709 Se esperaba una declaración, pero se encontró '*'. Ignorado hasta la siguiente declaración. demo_table.css:268
23:06:38.709 Propiedad desconocida '-moz-border-radius'. Declaración rechazada. demo_table.css:334
23:06:38.709 Se esperaba una declaración, pero se encontró '*'. Ignorado hasta la siguiente declaración.

DEBUG:

Error al interpretar el valor para 'background'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:13
```

23:11:15.408 
    Error al interpretar el valor para 'background'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:14
23:11:15.408 
    Error al interpretar el valor para 'background'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:15
23:11:15.408 
    Error al interpretar el valor para 'background'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:16
23:11:15.408 Se esperaba un color, pero se encontró 'top'. 
    Error al interpretar el valor para 'background'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:17
23:11:15.408 Se esperaba 'none' o una URL, pero se encontró 'progid'. 
    Error al interpretar el valor para 'filter'. Declaración rechazada. DT_Debug.css:18
23:11:15.408 Se esperaba una declaración, pero se encontró '*'. Ignorado hasta la siguiente declaración.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not strange at all, and has nothing to do with Spring, JSP or the errors you are getting in the console. It is because you are using `demo_table.css`. It is very easy to reproduce your problem :

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/as55Q/**

[image]

---

Here the difference when using the regular `jquery.dataTables.css`

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/VerEj/**

[image]

So all you have to do is to use `jquery.dataTables.css`